# How to make full use of multicore(only cpu mode) when using tensorflow on android phone?

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, multicore

System information

Platform: Android 6.0, arm64-v8a
TensorFlow installed from source(CPU mode only):
TensorFlow version (1.2.0)
Bazel version (0.5.2)
Describe the problem

When I trained a model by using google object-detection API, I put it to my android env, and use c++ API to run the PB file model on my phone, it has a slow running speed, and only 2 CPUs are fully utilized when there are 8 CPUs on my device. What should I do to make full use of the remaining CPUs on my mobile phone?

I use c++ API to run the model, here is my config to a session of tensorflow, but it is useless.Could some one help me?
Source code / logs

tensorflow::SessionOptions options;
tensorflow::ConfigProto &config = options.config;
config.mutable_device_count()->insert(google::protobuf::MapPair("cpu",8));
config.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(8);

Comment: Can you explain what device you're using, and how you're determining the CPU usage? I also recommend running your model in tensorflow/tools/benchmark to get a detailed log of which ops are taking the most time.

Comment: Oh,my cell phone is using  Snapdragon 625(8 cores) as cpu ,CPU usage is test by other tools, not only one tool, it is accurate ,I'm sure about this.@PeteWarden